# Rings with zero-divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

this might be an odd question but I know that in a ring with no zero-divisors $ac|bc$ implies $a|b$, if $c\neq 0$. So are there Rings with zero divisors where $ac|bc$ still implies $a|b$? Thank you.

Comment: I'm on my mobile, but in my head $\mathbb{Z_4}$ would work, wouldnt it?

Comment: I do not see any problems either, but I might have missed something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take the ring $\mathbb Z/6/\mathbb Z$. Let $3=c$, $a=5$ and $b=2$ then $ac=5$ and $bc=0$  so $5|0$    but  $5$ does not divide $2$.

Comment: Thank you. But this is exatly my problem. I know only know examples of rings with zero divisors where the implication does not work. But I would like to know if there are rings with zero divisors where  it works. And if not, how to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

> So are there Rings with zero divisors where $ac|bc$ still implies $a|b$? Thank you.

Yes, this is true in all rings but only if $c$ is not zero or zero divisor.